# Using "Try Ubuntu" Option and can't get out of it

Tags: installation

I used a pendrive( Universal usb installer) to install Ubuntu on my pc.

Here are the instructions that I followed :http://www.pendrivelinux.com/using-a-portable-virtualbox-to-run-linux-from-usb/
 (the pendrive is the virtual usb device )

Now, every time I boot the Ubuntu main page appear and
I am presented with three options:

```
Try Ubuntu
Install Ubuntu on harddrive
Boot from the first harddisk
```

I know if choose install Ubuntu on hard drive option, the window blow off.
So for like 3 months I chose "Try Ubuntu" option.

How can I get back to my previous window?
I know my window has been not yet wiped out...
Please give me advice.

Comment: What do you mean by the statement "the window blow off"?

Answer (score 0):

Windows will not be removed if you click the "on hardrive" option, it will give you an option to install Ubuntu, and also keep windows. To get back to the previous window either click the install button on the desktop on Ubuntu, or restart the computer leaving the pendrive in.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't installed ubuntu, you can boot from the first hard disk where your windows installation should still be. 
Best,